# can not build Qt5 framework by Yocto project for qemuarm

Tags: arm, qt5, qemu, yocto

I'm trying to run Qt5 framework through eglfs instead of X11 or wayland.
I'm trying to install Qt5 for qemuarm emualting `Raspberry pi 3` based on yocto `Rocko`.
This is my `bblayers.conf`:

```
# POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION is increased each time build/conf/bblayers.conf
# changes incompatibly
POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
SRCPATH = "/home/yocto/yocto"
BBFILES ?= ""

BBLAYERS ?= " \
    ${SRCPATH}/meta \
    ${SRCPATH}/meta-poky \
    ${SRCPATH}/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
    ${SRCPATH}/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
    ${SRCPATH}/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
    ${SRCPATH}/meta-openembedded/meta-perl \
    ${SRCPATH}/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
    ${SRCPATH}/meta-qt5 \
    ${SRCPATH}/meta-raspberrypi \
    ${SRCPATH}/meta-security \
```

and this is my `local.conf`:

```
MACHINE ??= "qemuarm"
DL_DIR ?= "${TOPDIR}/../downloads"
DISTRO ?= "poky"
PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_deb"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES ?= "debug-tweaks"
USER_CLASSES ?= "buildstats image-mklibs image-prelink"
PATCHRESOLVE = "noop"
BB_DISKMON_DIRS = "\
    STOPTASKS,${TMPDIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${DL_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${SSTATE_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,/tmp,100M,100K \
    ABORT,${TMPDIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,${DL_DIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,${SSTATE_DIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,/tmp,10M,1K"

LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST = "commercial"

CONF_VERSION = "1"
PREFERRED_VERSION_linux-raspberrypi = "4.%"
DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = "x11 wayland"
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " systemd opengl pam ${DISTRO_FEATURES_LIBC}"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "systemd"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES += "package-management splash"

INHERIT+="toaster buildhistory"
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += "openssh"
ENABLE_UART="1"
#PACKAGECONFIG_append_qtbase = " accessibility eglfs fontconfig gles2 linuxfb"

################### QT ######################
QT_DEV_TOOLS = " \
    qtbase-dev \
    qtbase-mkspecs \
    qtbase-plugins \
    qtbase-tools \
    qtserialport-dev \
    qtserialport-mkspecs \
"

QT_TOOLS = " \
    qtbase \
    qtserialport \
"

FONTS = " \
    fontconfig \
    fontconfig-utils \
    ttf-bitstream-vera \
"

TSLIB = " \
    tslib \
    tslib-conf \
    tslib-calibrate \
    tslib-tests \
    tspress \
"

QT5_PKGS = " \
    qt3d \
    qtcharts \
    qtdeclarative \
    qtdeclarative-plugins \
    qtdeclarative-qmlplugins \
    qtgraphicaleffects \
    qtlocation-plugins \
    qtmultimedia \
    qtquickcontrols2 \
    qtsensors-plugins \
    qtserialbus \
    qtsvg \
    qtwebsockets-qmlplugins \
    qtvirtualkeyboard \
    qtxmlpatterns \
"

QML_APPS = " \
    qqtest \
"

CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += " \
    ${FONTS} \
    ${QT_TOOLS} \
    ${QT5_PKGS} \
    cinematicexperience \
"
```

I'm trying to build this image `bitbake rpi-hwup-image`

the problem is with qtbase, it fails with this error:

```
| ERROR: Feature 'opengl-desktop' was enabled, but the pre-condition '(config.win32 && !config.winrt && !features.opengles2 && (config.msvc || libs.opengl))
|                           || (!config.watchos && !config.win32 && libs.opengl)' failed.
| 
| ERROR: The OpenGL functionality tests failed!
| You might need to modify the include and library search paths by editing QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL[_ES2],
| QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENGL[_ES2] and QMAKE_LIBS_OPENGL[_ES2] in the mkspec for your platform.
```

---

### Update

This problem is solved by uncommenting `PACKAGECONFIG_append_qtbase` and it has a typo so, it's been updated to be `PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-qtbase`.

I added those lines too:
`PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-qemu-native = " sdl"
PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-nativesdk-qemu = " sdl"`.

I comment out this line `LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST = "commercial"`.

but it fails again at qtbase build by this error (this is the tail of the log file) (I deleted the `tmp` folder and started `bitbake rpi-hwup-image` again but it went to the same error)

```
| cd windowflags/ && ( test -e Makefile || /home/yocto/yocto/build/RP3_Qt/tmp/work/armv5e-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtbase/5.9.3+gitAUTOINC+4d8ae444c2-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/qt5/qmake -o Makefile /home/yocto/yocto/build/RP3_Qt/tmp/work/armv5e-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtbase/5.9.3+gitAUTOINC+4d8ae444c2-r0/git/examples/widgets/widgets/windowflags/windowflags.pro -qtconf /home/yocto/yocto/build/RP3_Qt/tmp/work/armv5e-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtbase/5.9.3+gitAUTOINC+4d8ae444c2-r0/build/bin/qt.conf ) && make -f Makefile
| make[4]: Entering directory '/home/yocto/yocto/build/RP3_Qt/tmp/work/armv5e-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtbase/5.9.3+gitAUTOINC+4d8ae444c2-r0/build/examples/widgets/widgets/windowflags'
| compiling /home/yocto/yocto/build/RP3_Qt/tmp/work/armv5e-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtbase/5.9.3+gitAUTOINC+4d8ae444c2-r0/git/examples/widgets/widgets/windowflags/controllerwindow.cpp
| compiling /home/yocto/yocto/build/RP3_Qt/tmp/work/armv5e-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtbase/5.9.3+gitAUTOINC+4d8ae444c2-r0/git/examples/widgets/widgets/windowflags/previewwindow.cpp
| linking wiggly
| make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/yocto/yocto/build/RP3_Qt/tmp/work/armv5e-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtbase/5.9.3+gitAUTOINC+4d8ae444c2-r0/build/examples/widgets/widgets/wiggly'
| compiling /home/yocto/yocto/build/RP3_Qt/tmp/work/armv5e-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtbase/5.9.3+gitAUTOINC+4d8ae444c2-r0/git/examples/widgets/widgets/windowflags/main.cpp
| linking validators
| generating .moc/moc_predefs.h
| moc /home/yocto/yocto/build/RP3_Qt/tmp/work/armv5e-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtbase/5.9.3+gitAUTOINC+4d8ae444c2-r0/git/examples/widgets/widgets/windowflags/controllerwindow.h
| make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/yocto/yocto/build/RP3_Qt/tmp/work/armv5e-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtbase/5.9.3+gitAUTOINC+4d8ae444c2-r0/build/examples/widgets/widgets/validators'
| moc /home/yocto/yocto/build/RP3_Qt/tmp/work/armv5e-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtbase/5.9.3+gitAUTOINC+4d8ae444c2-r0/git/examples/widgets/widgets/windowflags/previewwindow.h
| compiling .moc/moc_controllerwindow.cpp
| compiling .moc/moc_previewwindow.cpp
| linking windowflags
| make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/yocto/yocto/build/RP3_Qt/tmp/work/armv5e-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtbase/5.9.3+gitAUTOINC+4d8ae444c2-r0/build/examples/widgets/widgets/windowflags'
| make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/yocto/yocto/build/RP3_Qt/tmp/work/armv5e-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtbase/5.9.3+gitAUTOINC+4d8ae444c2-r0/build/examples/widgets/widgets'
| make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/yocto/yocto/build/RP3_Qt/tmp/work/armv5e-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtbase/5.9.3+gitAUTOINC+4d8ae444c2-r0/build/examples/widgets'
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/yocto/yocto/build/RP3_Qt/tmp/work/armv5e-poky-linux-gnueabi/qtbase/5.9.3+gitAUTOINC+4d8ae444c2-r0/build/examples'
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution according to this [page](http://ms-cheminfo.com/?q=node/69&language=ja).

The configuration part -at this page- says something about ommiting the tests part at this option `-nomake tests`, it's the same part that fails at the compiling stage of `qtbase`.
so after cleaning qtbase and adding this part to my `local.conf`

```
PACKAGECONFIG_remove_pn-qtbase = " tests gl"
```

`gl` is omitted too because we want to build `qtbase` for `eglfs` not for desktop.